# Android Dagger - two provider methods which one gets chosen

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

Lets say i have an activity like this:

```
 public class ListBlogsActivity extends Activity {
  @Inject ObjectMapper mapper;


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Put Dagger into action
    ObjectGraph.create(new ListBlogsModule()).inject(this);  //Dagger

    //do a bunch of other things etc...
  }
```

Now lets say i have a dagger module which i define to inject a ObjectMapper into the activity like this:

```
    @Module(injects = ListBlogsActivity.class)
public class ListBlogsModule {
  @Provides ObjectMapper objectMapper() {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //do some more stuff ..blah blah
    return mapper;
  }
}
```

Now here is my key question:

lets say i have another module which we define to inject into the same activity a ObjectMapper:

```
@Module(injects = ListBlogsActivity.class)
public class ListBlogs2Module {
  @Provides ObjectMapper objectMapper2() {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //do some more stuff ..blah blah
    return mapper;
  }
}
```

What will happen, how will dagger differentiate this since i have two modules which provide an injection of the sdame type ObjectMapper - which one gets chosen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not compile.

If you have two dependencies of the same type in different modules, you have to mark one as the overriding one. Set below line on your module annotation.

```
overrides = true
```